# webservice request on all servers in a weblogic cluster

Tags: rest, web-services, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have Weblogic 12c configuration where under 1 Admin there are 7 managed servers. 
I want to deploy a WebService in such a way that When request comes for one perticular resource let say /search.java, It will do the same operation on all 7 servers (at the same time), and return the 7 results/responses.

I can achieve this using code in webservice (hopefully), is there any way in weblogic I can do this?

***Edited***
I want to search a String in log files on 7 servers. If I deploy my code to search a string in log by usual way. It will search only on any one of the 7 servers, log files on other 6 will remain unsearched. In order to search the string on all 7, I need to execute the search code on all 7 servers.

Comment: I don't understand the use case of your scenario. It is more likely you want to have 7 different instance of your applications. why do you need that ?

Comment: Yes, we need more clarification. If I receive one request and then trigger the 7 managed servers, where I should send the 7 responses ?

Comment: @Ravi Updated the question

Comment: @devwebcl Updated the question

Comment: @Chaitra what takes so long to respond ? also where are those logs are getting created ? in same machine or different machine ?

Comment: @Ravi It does not take long but the search query has to be targeted exclusively for each server.The logs are getting created in 7 different machines.

Comment: @Chaitra I wasn't saying about system performance, instead I was saying what is taking so long to you to respond each comment . You doesn't seems to be serious for your issue.